# How to do SPARQL UPDATE with Perl?

Tags: perl, sparql

My understanding is that
[`AtteanX::Store::SPARQL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/AtteanX::Store::SPARQL)
supports only query, not update.

So I guess I'll use
[`RDF::Query::Client`](https://metacpan.org/pod/RDF::Query::Client),
which is in line with the older `RDF::Trine`.

Comment: What is your question? You appear to have resolved this issue yourself.

Comment: Almost works but there's no way to check if it was successful. On success it returns null and `->error()` is `Response of type '' could not be parsed.`  https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=125913

Comment: @borodin thanks for the reassurance, but is this really the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

```
use constant UPDATE => "https://.../update";
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
use constant DEBUG => 7; # dump SPARQL POST: 0 off, 1 uri, 2 status, 3 title, 4 params, 5 headers, 6 cookies, 7 text, 8 content
if (DEBUG) {use LWP::ConsoleLogger::Easy qw(debug_ua)}

my $update = RDF::Query::Client->new("insert {...} where {...}");
debug_ua ($ua, DEBUG) if DEBUG;
$update->execute(UPDATE, {UserAgent => $ua, QueryParameter=>"update", QueryMethod =>"POST", AuthUsername=>USER, AuthPassword=>PASS});
# no way to check success
```